# this error occurs when i press on the create button in create post form

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request sql exception asp.net core .
SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Posts_AspNetUsers_AuthorId". The conflict occurred in database "LostKidsDb", table "dbo.AspNetUsers", column 'Id'.

Here is the Post Model

```
    [Key]
    public int PostId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Descripition { get; set; }

    public string  Image { get; set; }

    public string Address{ get; set; }

    [Display(Name ="Category")]
    public int CategoryId{ get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
    public Category Category{ get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Sub-Category")]
    public int SubCategoryId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SubCategoryId")]
    public SubCategory SubCategory { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Author-Id")]
    [Required]
    public string AuthorId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AuthorId")]
    public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Author-Name")]
    public string AuthorName { get; set; }

    public enum PostStatus
    {
        Pending,
        Approved,
        Rejected
    }
    public PostStatus Status { get; set; }
```

Here is the Application user model

```
public class ApplicationUser:IdentityUser
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string StreetAddress { get; set; }

    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string Governorate { get; set; }

    public string  City { get; set; }
}
```

This is the create razor view page in user controller:

```
  <div class="col-5">
            @if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
            {
                {
                    ApplicationUser applicationUser = await UserManager.GetUserAsync(User);

                    <input readonly asp-for="Post.AuthorName" value=" @applicationUser.Name " class="form-control" />

                }
            }
            <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="Post.AuthorName"></span>

        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-2">
            <label hidden asp-for="Post.AuthorId" class="col-form-label"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-5">
            @if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
            {
                {
                    ApplicationUser applicationUser = await UserManager.GetUserAsync(User);

                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Post.AuthorId" value=" @applicationUser.Id " class="form-control" />

                }
            }
```

Here is the Create Method in Post Controller in User Area:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
       
        return View(PostVM);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [ActionName("Create")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreatePost()
    {
        //if (ModelState.IsValid)
        //{
            
            //in case the user didn't upload an image while creating a post a default image will be uploaded with the post

            string ImagePath = @" \Images\download.png";

            //uploaded images of the created post will be saved into this static file
            var files = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files;
            if (files.Count > 0)
            {
                string webroot = webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath;

                // change the name of images uploaded to avoid duplicate names so every uploaded image
                // will take the name of the date of its uploading
                string ImageName = DateTime.Now.ToFileTime().ToString() + Path.GetExtension(files[0].FileName);

                FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(webroot, "Images", ImageName), FileMode.Create);
                files[0].CopyTo(fileStream);

                ImagePath = @"\Images\" + ImageName;
            //}
            PostVM.Post.Image = ImagePath;
            db.Posts.Add(PostVM.Post);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));

        }
        return View(PostVM);
    }
```

Comment: please provide code-behind (controller/action) in your question

Comment: This is the Post Controller in the User Area where i have an issue with the create method

Comment: You didn't receive any model in create method however you save a null object which fired exception

I suggest you to search on internet how make crud operation in asp. Net

Comment: my suggestion is removing `ForeignKey` relationship. foreign key will bring extra constraint. You may write several insert action to keep the table relationships in your code. And then you can write comment on them to explain that relationship for back-forward maintance. And it will be helpful when you need to delete rows in tables